# Calling Next/Prev Query from Database Search Results

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a database with Customer information that's linked with other tables.

I'm trying to create a webpage with a search option to search the database.
I've got the search function working.

I would like to be able get the output to show only one result at a time.
I've also got that working.

What I would like is to to be able to use a Next and Prev button to cycle between the different results from that query.
From my understanding (kinda new to coding) when the search is done all that data is put into an array.  This array has ID's assigned to it.
So Searching "Smith" may have 10 results. Results in the array would be 0-9.
My logic was to have the initial search display result 0 then when Next is pressed have a function increase RecNum by 1 then re display. The codes is set to seek by the RecNum so Next would show result 2 (line 1 in the array).

Getting that to work is where my problem is.  I'm not even sure how to approach that end. (Did I mention I'm new to coding).

Right now I'm using Javascript to make sure the adding and subtracting on button press is working.  I'm lost how how to get the new new RecNum to translate to the PHP $RecNum and re display the data.
Any help with code would be greatly appreciated.  I'm not set in stone on using JavaScript.  I am open to using _Sessions or AJAX.  What ever will work fine.

Here is the code I have now.
The search works and the New Search button works but as of right now all the Prev and Next buttons do is increase/decrease the number of RecNum and output it at the bottom of the page.

```html
<?php
require 'Connect.php';
$output = '';
$RecNum = 0;
//$Prev = $RecNum - 1;
//$Next = $RecNum + 1;
//$_Post['Prev'] = $Prev;
//$_Post['Next'] = $Next;


//collect
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
  $searchq = $_POST['search'];
  // Joins and tables with realationships and allows for searching of the searchable areas
  
  $sql="SELECT aps.*, customers.*, equipment.*, routableip.*
    FROM customers  
 LEFT JOIN aps ON customers.AP_ID = aps.AP_ID
    LEFT JOIN equipment ON equipment.Cust_ID = customers.Cust_ID
    LEFT JOIN routableip ON routableip.Cust_ID = customers.Cust_ID
    WHERE (equipment.ESN LIKE '%$searchq%') 
    OR (equipment.WMAC LIKE '%$searchq%') 
 OR (equipment.UnitIP LIKE '%$searchq%') 
    OR (equipment.Cust_ID LIKE '%$searchq%') 
 OR (equipment.AP_ID LIKE '%$searchq%')
 OR (equipment.SN LIKE '%$searchq%')
 OR (customers.Account LIKE '%$searchq%')
 OR (customers.AlternatePhone LIKE '%$searchq%') 
 OR (customers.Phone LIKE '%$searchq%')
 OR (Routableip.Routable_IP LIKE '%$searchq%')
 OR (customers.Address LIKE '%$searchq%')
    OR (customers.LastName LIKE '%$searchq%')";

  
  $query= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
  if($count == 0){
    $output = 'There was no search results!';
  
  
  
  mysqli_free_result($query);
  }
  else{      
    //while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  mysqli_data_seek($query,$RecNum);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
  
  $Account = $row[11];
  $LastName = $row[3];
  $FirstName = $row[4];
  $Address = $row[5];
  $City = $row[6];
  $State = $row[7];
  $Zip = $row[8];
  $Phone = $row[9];
  $AlternatePhone = $row[10];

  $UnitIP = $row[22];
  $BridgeMode = $row[23];
  $RIP = $row[27];
  $AP = $row[1];
  
  
  $NewDate = $row[21];
  $SimpleModel = $row[18];
  $Manufacturer = $row[19];
  $Frequency = $row[20];
  $SN = $row[16];
  $ESN = $row[15];
  $WMAC = $row[14];
   
  
 
      $output .= '<div>
    <br> <h2>Customer Information</h2>
    <br> Account Number: '.$Account.'
    <br> Name: '.$LastName.', '.$FirstName.'
    <br> Address: '.$Address.'
    <br> City: '.$City.' State: '.$State.' Zip: '.$Zip.'
    <br> Phone #: '.$Phone.'
    
    <br> <h2>Connection Information</h2>
    <br> Unit IP: '.$UnitIP.'
    <br> Bridge Mode: '.$BridgeMode.'
    <br> Routable IP: '.$RIP.'
    <br> AP: '.$AP.'
    
    <br> <h2>Unit Information</h2>
    <br> New Date: '.$NewDate.' Model: '.$SimpleModel.'
    <br> Manufacturer: '.$Manufacturer.' Frequency: '.$Frequency.'
    <br> SN: '.$SN.'
    <br> ESN: '.$ESN.'
    <br> WMAC: '.$WMAC.'
    </div>';
  
 
  
 }
   mysqli_free_result($query);
 }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<title>Search</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var RecNum = 0;
function add(){
     RecNum++;
     document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = RecNum;
}
function sub(){
 RecNum--;
 document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = RecNum;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for Information" autocomplete="off"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Search" />
 
 
</form>

<?php print("$output");?>

 <button class="button Prev1" onclick="sub()" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Prev</span></button>
 <a href="" class="button button3" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>New Search</span></a></button>
 <button class="button Next2" onclick="add()" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Next</span></button>
 
<br>
 
<div id="display"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(RecNum);</script></div>

 
PHP:<?php print($RecNum);?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not 100% sure if I get the gist of it, but generally / high-level you'd want to do either 1 of these 2 things: 1. return 1 result with backend/php to the frontend. You could statically render the page no javascript needed. next-parameter could be encoded in the url querystring which can be parsed serverside / php. OR 2. return a batch of results, say, 10, through ajax, and encode the results in a javascript (json) array. Then, implement your prev/next logic in javascript. Option 2 gives you the benefit of not having to do a server request for each prev/next click. Good luck!